# how to play live streaming video using mpmovieplayer in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

how to play live streaming video using mpmovieplayer in iphone sdk ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How play the video using “HTTP Live Streaming” in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720068/how-play-the-video-using-http-live-streaming-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str_url]];

mediaPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;                             

[mediaPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your video file in the apache server path `/var/www/html/audiofile.mp4`

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:   [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://IPaddress of server/audiofile.mp4"]];
[player play];
```

This way is supported only in apache server. Otherwise you should use mediasegmenter with the http live streaming method.